# How can I convert 15300504579PRI03 to 15,3,005,04579,PRI,03 in C#

Tags: c#, regex

How can I convert `15300504579PRI03` to `15,3,005,04579,PRI,03` in C#. And I have to do this for each line as shown below in a text file

```
15300504579PRI03
15300504841PRI03
15300504843PRI03
15300504847PRI03
```

Comment: Are there any **constants** in those values you need to search for?  For instance, is there always a "PRI" in there?  Is it always 16 chars long and you can simply break it apart based on the lengths of the "columns"?  Are there multiple values per line?  Do you really want a comma separated list?...or do you want an array/list?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution that doesn't rely on regular expressions:

```
public string Convert(string input)
{
    var list = new List<char>(input.ToCharArray());
    list.Insert(2, ',');
    list.Insert(4, ',');
    list.Insert(8, ',');
    list.Insert(14, ',');
    list.Insert(18, ',');
    return new string(list.ToArray());
}
```

and here's how to use it:

```
var input = "15300504579PRI03";
var replaced = Convert(input); //replaced will contain: 15,3,005,04579,PRI,03
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use capturing groups to capture all the content you want and then create a new string concatenating `,` after each captured content.

For instance, you can use this regex:

```
(.{2})(.)(.{3})(.{5})(.{3})(.{2})
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/iQ8wP4/1)**

With a replacement string:

```
$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6
```

Code:

```
var pattern = @"(.{2})(.)(.{3})(.{5})(.{3})(.{2})";
var replaced = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex with groups. Then parse the first number. You could also use additional groups with a regex or substring to parse out the prefixed number. (2num)(1num)(3num)(5num)(letters)(number)

```
// URL that generated this code:
// http://txt2re.com/index-csharp.php3?s=15300504579PRI03%20&1&4&5

using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string txt="15300504579PRI03 ";

      string re1="(\\d+)";  // Integer Number 1
      string re2="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))";   // Word 1
      string re3="(\\d+)";  // Integer Number 2

      Regex r = new Regex(re1+re2+re3,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Singleline);
      Match m = r.Match(txt);
      if (m.Success)
      {
            String int1=m.Groups[1].ToString();
            String word1=m.Groups[2].ToString();
            String int2=m.Groups[3].ToString();
            Console.Write("("+int1.ToString()+")"+"("+word1.ToString()+")"+"("+int2.ToString()+")"+"\n");
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}

//-----
// Paste the code into a new Console Application
//-----
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach...

```
using System;

public class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = "15300504579PRI03";
        string output = Convert(input); 
        Console.WriteLine(input);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }

    static public string Convert(string input)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(input);
        int[] commasAt = {2, 3, 6, 11, 14};
        for(int i = commasAt.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)   
        {
            sb.Insert(commasAt[i], ',');
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

}
```